# How do I limit the player from moving around while airborne?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am extremely new to GameDev in Unity and need help with a problem with player movement. The way that my movement is set up, lets you turn and move while you are in mid-air, which gives it an unrealistic feel. I was wondering how I would go about making it to where once you jump in a direction, you can't change it until you return to the ground.

I understand that it should just be a simple boolean that checks if the player is in the air, I just don't know how to code it within my current movement script. Thanks.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 velocity;

    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public CharacterController controller;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    bool isGrounded;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: You already know if your player `isGrounded`, so when the player is not grounded, you can just ignore the player input so do something like if(isGrounded){return;} before the input. The one issue with this is it looks like you are calculating your own gravity? Even though with a rigidbody gravity should already effect your object unless you turned gravity on the component off.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable it when you are not on ground with a simple if statement:

```
 public float speed = 12f;
 public float gravity = -9.81f;
 public CharacterController controller;
 public float jumpHeight = 3f;

 public Transform groundCheck;
 public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
 public LayerMask groundMask;

 bool isGrounded;

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
      isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

     if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
     {
          velocity.y = -2f;
     }

     float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
     float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
     Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
     if (!isGrounded)
     {
         controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
     }
     if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
     {
         velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
     }

      velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

      controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
 }
 }
```

What I did, was adding an if statement to the controller.Move() function. Here is what it looks like without the rest of the code:

```
if (isGrounded)
{
    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

This is what I wrote. The if statement says: if the character is on the ground, then move it. This means it will stop updating the position of the character while in the air.

If you want more realistic physics, add this to your script:

```
if (isGrounded)
{
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
else
{
    velocity.x = Mathf.Sqrt(move.x * var2);
    velocity.z = Mathf.Sqrt(move.z * var2);
}
```

I copied your jump script, and changed it slightly to replicate the physics you might want. Change the names of var1 and var2. Var 2 is the amount of force to be applied when you are in the air, just experiment with what you want.

Comment: I applied the code and for some reason, it just stops me as soon as I jump and doesn't continue to move on with the jump. I successfully got the part where it stops taking in WASD input but at the cost of freezing the jump. I think I need a way to remember which way I am facing right before I jump so that the engine can continue the jump. I just don't know if that would require a new vector or what though. Still though, thank you for the help!